# Sprite Optimization?

Tags: css, image, browser, inline, css-sprites

Does anyone know how images are loaded per browser? For inline images, do two calls to the same image trigger two server requests or just one? How are subsequent calls to an image that has been downloaded handled?

For CSS images, are all images called within your CSS loaded when the CSS file is called or is it when individual classes calling the images are used? As an extreme example, if I have a CSS file that calls 200 separate images but only one of those images is called on the first page load, do all 200 get called or just the one? How does loading differ by browser if any?

Comment: Changed the title of this as it evolved into a discussion more about how to optimize sprites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image urls should cause only one hit on the server PER PAGE. For that one page's hit, the browser can assume that the image will be unchanged, even if the image appears multiple times on the page

For the next page, the browser will tend to do a "if-modified-since" request for the image, and only get a new image if it has been modified since that last night. But again, it'll only do it ONCE per page.

Once the image has been downloaded and cached, you'll most likely see only 200 get requests and 304 not-modified  responses until the image falls out of the cache.

Comment: So for the second part of my question, do all images referenced in the CSS file cause a server hit or just the ones being used on the current page?

Comment: as far as I know, any url() reference in css will cause that url to be hit. maybe there's a browser out there that optimizes things by only fetching ones that are actually used in the page, but who knows.

Comment: The reason I ask is I'd like to determine if it is better to use one master sprite or multiple smaller sprites.  For example, if I have 10 images I make into a sprite and 5 of those images are only used on a 3rd of my site then is it better two have to sprites?  If all images in a CSS file are downloaded on page load then I would think no, but if only the images within classes being called by the page are downloaded then I would think yes.  Thoughts?

Comment: One master sprite. The few kbytes of extra overhead for the bigger image will be more than made up by reducing the number of extra "has this image change" requests that the individual sprites would produce. Remember - every unique image in a page has to be validated for every page view. 5 sprites on a page = 5 hits on the server resulting in a 304 not-modified response.

Comment: Do you know approximately where that trade off happens?  As an extreme example, lets say I have a master sprite that is 800k. What if 700k of that image is composed of images only called by 10 pages of my 300 page site.  One sprite or two? Where does the trade off approximately happen.  Is there a rough conversion guide available? X KB = 1 Server Request

Comment: depends on network speed and latency, how often the sprite needs to be refresh, etc... Impossible to say because there's just too many variables.

Answer (score 1):

You actually make a call for every image, that's why it is advised to use [CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites) when appropriate

Comment: So even if the image is called by a class that is not used on the page it will still get loaded because it is in the CSS file?

Comment: And how are subsequent calls to the same image handled? Does it matter that I call the same sprite 20 times or should I string the classes together and only call the sprite once?

Comment: the browser won't be calling for the sprite 20 times, 1 time is enough, since the next time it'll be already loaded

Comment: So for the second part of my question, do all images referenced in the CSS file cause a server hit or just the ones being used on the current page?

Comment: Only the ones being used on the current page will be loaded, however, it may vary depending on the browser, I'm not sure.

Comment: The reason I ask is I'd like to determine if it is better to use one master sprite or multiple smaller sprites.  For example, if I have 10 images I make into a sprite and 5 of those images are only used on a 3rd of my site then is it better two have to sprites?  If all images in a CSS file are downloaded on page load then I would think no, but if only the images within classes being called by the page are downloaded then I would think yes.  Thoughts?

Comment: IMO, the best thing to do is to have sprites for related images, for example, button background + hover background of the same button, icons which are displayed in the same page (a toolbar for example) ... just don't spend too much time thinking about this, try to keep your images web-optimized and relatively small and it should be fine